# Update a google spreadsheet by row id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-sheets-api

I need to update the information in a specific row in the google spreadsheets.
I get the data from the inputs in the front end, and the number of the row that I need to update from the userID.

I tried to use ajax, sending the URL of the form response, but what it does is adding a new row.

Is there a way to send the data and the row ID, so I can update that row in the google sheet?

I use tabletop.js to get/read the data from the google sheets, but dont know if it work to update

function Update() {

```
var ID = userID;

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/key/formResponse?',
    data: {
        "entry.2085722051": v_NAME
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (d) {
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        $('#success-msg').show();
        $('#form').hide();
    }
});
```

}

I expect the function Update() to update the row [number] on the google sheet by using the [number ID] of the user.
But what actual happens is that the function save the data in a new row.